# Dyanmic Queue with Priority, add function not working

Tags: c, queue

This is my take on how to implement a queue linked queue. As the add function isn't working properly, I a not able to test the other functions either, beside new_queue which seems to be working.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Qelement {
    struct Qelement *next;
    int prio;
    const char *dataptr;
}; 

typedef struct Qelement *Queue;

// creates an empty queue
Queue new_queue ()
{
        Queue q = (Queue)malloc(sizeof(struct Qelement));
        q->next = NULL;
        q->prio = 0;
        q->dataptr = NULL;     
        return q;
}

// removes the queue and all its elements
void delete_queue (Queue q)
{
        Queue tmp;
        while (q->next != NULL)
        {
                tmp = q->next;
                free (q);
                q = tmp;
        }

        free(q);
}

// emmpties queue
void clear (Queue q)
{
        Queue tmp;
        while (q->next != NULL)
        {
                tmp = q->next;
                free (q);
                q = tmp;
        }

        q->next = NULL;
        q->prio = 0;
        q->dataptr = NULL;
}

// get length of queue
int size (Queue q)
{
        Queue orginal = q;

        int length = 0;
        while (q->next != NULL)
        {
                ++length;
                q = q->next;
        }

        ++length;
        q = orginal;

        return length;
}

// add an element to queue
void add (Queue q, int priority, Datatyp *d)
{
        Queue tmp;
        Queue previous = q;

        Queue element = (Queue)malloc (sizeof(struct Qelement));
        element->next = NULL;
        element->prio = priority;
        element->dataptr = d;

        if (priority > previous->prio)
        {
                tmp = q;
                q = element;
                element->next = tmp;           
        }
        else
        {
                if (previous->next != NULL)
                {
                        while (priority <= previous->next->prio)
                        {
                                previous = previous->next;
                        }

                        previous->next = element;
                        element->next = previous->next->next;
                }
                else
                {
                        //previous->next = element;
                }
        }
}

// return first element
Datatyp *get_first (Queue q)
{
        return q->dataptr;
}

// removes first element
void remove_first(Queue q)
{
        Queue tmp = q->next;
        q = q->next;
        free(tmp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *daniel = "Daniel";
    const char *lisa = "Lisa";
    const char *a[] = {"Kalle", "Olle", "Eva", lisa, "Stina", 
                      "Peter", "Anna", daniel, "Johan", "Maria"};
    const int correctOrder1[] = {3, 7, 2, 6, 1, 5, 9, 0, 4, 8 };
    const int correctOrder2[] = {5, 4, 7, 3, 6};

    Queue q = new_queue();
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        add(q, i%4, a[i]); 
    }

    printf("Size = %d\n\n", size(q)); // says 1, should say 10
    ...
}
```

The last printf, in the main function says 1, so my take is that the add part is not working properly. Any pointer?

Answer (score 0):

In function `add`, you need to pass a `Queue*`, in order to actually change it outside the function:

```
void add (Queue* q, int priority, Datatyp *d)
{
    ...
    Queue previous = *q;
    ...
    if (priority > previous->prio)
    {
        tmp = *q;
        *q = element;
        element->next = tmp;           
    }
    ...
}
```

Then, in function `main`, you need to call `add(&q, i%4, a[i])` instead of `add(q, i%4, a[i])`.

**BTW, you have the same problem in every other function that attempts to change `q`!!!**

So an alternative way to solve this problem is by declaring `Queue q` as a global variable, instead of passing it to each function. But that will prevent you from using several different queues of course...

Comment: As of 'typedef struct Qelement *Queue;' will that still be a problem? Queue is already a pointer to Qelement struct.

Comment: It doesn't matter. When you change a local variable passed to a function, it will only change in the scope of that function. You need to pass the address of that variable, and inside the function, change the memory contents of that address. In other words, call `func(&q,...)` and inside `func`, set `*q = ...`.

Comment: void getWordsFromFile (char **str) { ... str[0] = ...; } will work, I am certain of that, I am using it in another function, calling getWordsFromFile without a reference from the main function. I am already passing a pointer, the function takes a pointer, it does not have a local stored variable. It is already working directly on the memory.